# How to avoid chaining WHERE .. IN statements in SQL?

Tags: sql

Here is a sample query:

```
SELECT customerName from customers 
WHERE customerNUMBER IN 
( SELECT customerNumber FROM orders 
  WHERE orderNumber 
    IN ( SELECT orderNumber FROM orderdetails 
    INNER JOIN products on orderdetails.productCode = products.productCode 
    where products.buyPrice > 100 ));
```

I believe the tables are self explanatory.

Is there a better way to do this?

SQL noob here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My suggestion would be to change this to [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) syntax instead of all of the WHERE/IN clause filtering:

```
select c.customerName
from customer c
inner join orders o
  on c.customerNumber = o.customerNumber
inner join orderdetails od
  on o.orderNumber = od.orderNumber
inner join products p
  on od.productCode = p.productCode
where p.buyPrice > 100;
```

If needed you might have to add a DISTINCT to the query in the event there are duplicates.

Comment: If you adopt this method you will notice two things. First you will gain a huge performance boost. Second your dba will stop hitting you.

Comment: I would recommend adding distinct or group by though...  This very well could return duplicate records.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Your question is to whom?

Comment: @KorayTugay To the `JOIN` gods.

Answer (score 8):

Use normal inner joins throughout, and toss in a group by or a distinct clause if you need to eliminate dups:

```
select customers.*
from customers
join orders on ...
join orderdetails on ...
join products on ...
group by customers.customerNumber
```

Comment: +1 for the `group by` - obviously `customers.*` cannot be used when grouping only by `customerNumber` in some RDBMS

Answer (score 2):

`EXISTS` allows you to combine all the subquery parts. Duplicates are not an issue:

- only the `customers` table is visible from the outer query
- `EXISTS` yields a boolean result for each `customers` row:

--

```
SELECT customerName from customers cc
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT * 
        FROM orders oo
        JOIN orderdetails od ON od.orderNumber = oo.orderNumber
        JOIN products pr ON od.productCode = pr.productCode
        WHERE oo.customerNUMBER = cc.customerNumber
        AND pr.buyPrice > 100 
        );
```